# AngularJS - Convert Object to Array for UI Bootstrap Pagination

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I know this might have been already answered, but I have been unsuccessful in applying any solutions I found to my example. I am trying to enabled pagination on my products list page using UI Bootstrap and allow the user to filter said results with a search.

I have an object that is defined as such:

```
$scope.products = [{"_id": ObjectID("0000000"), "name":"Product", "description": "Product Description"}];
```

So far I have been able to pull my products from a restangular service, but I am getting the following console error: `Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received {}` when I added the pagination/search functionality. I know I need to convert my object to an array, but I have not been able to successfully convert it. The two examples I tried are posted below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**My Products list view**

```
<div ng-controller="paginationCtrl" class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <form>
                <div class="input-group product-searchs" ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="searchProducts">Search</label>
                    <span class="input-group-addon search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchProducts" ng-model="search.name" placeholder="Search for products">
                    <span class="input-group-addon clear-icon">
                        <button type="button" ng-click="clearSearch()">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a ui-sref="productDetails({id:product._id})"  class="list-group-item clearfix" ng-repeat="product in filteredProducts = (products | filter: search | startFrom: (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage | limitTo: itemsPerPage | orderBy:orderProp)">
                <div class="page-header clearfix">
                    <h2 class="pull-left"><i class="fa fa-diamond"></i> {{product.name}}</h2>
                    <span class="pull-right product-price {{product.price | currency}}</span>
                </div>
                {{product.description}}
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <pagination class="pull-right" page="currentPage" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" ng-change="pageChanged() items-per-page="itemsPerPage" num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know I might have some extra dependencies injections, which I will remove once I get it working correctly.

**My controller**

```
angular.module('gemStoreApp')
   .controller('paginationCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', 'filterFilter', 'productsService', 'Restangular', '$filter', function ($scope, $log, filterFilter', productsService, Restangular, $filter) {

   $scope.search = {}

   $scope.filteredProducts = [];

   //Option 1
   angular.forEach($scope.products, function(product) {
       $scope.filteredProducts.push(product);
   });

   //Option 2
   //for (var key in $scope.products) {
       //var tempProducts = {};
       //tempProducts[key] = $scope.products[key];
       //$scope.filteredProducts.push(tempProducts);
   //});

   $scope.currentPage = 1;
   $scope.maxSize = 100;
   $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;

   $scope.$watch('search', function(newVal, oldVal) {
       $scope.filteredProducts = filterFilter($scope.products, newVal);
       $scope.totalItems = $scope.filteredProducts.length;
   }, true);

   //I also tried this
   //$scope.$watch('search, function(newSearch) {
       //$scope.filteredProducts = $filter('filter')($scope.products, $scope.search);
       // $scope.totalItems = $scope.filteredProducts.length;
   //});

   }])
```

**My service**

```
angular.module('gemStoreApp.productService',['ngResource'])
    .factory('productsService', function(Restangular) {
        return Restangular.service('products');
    });
```

**My Products Controller**

```
angular.module('gemStoreApp')
    .controller('ProductsCtrl', ['$scope', 'productsService', function ($scope, productsService) {
        $scope.products = {};
        productsService.getList().then(function(products){
            $scope.products = products;
        });
    }]);
```

Added the Restangular `setRestangularFields` and `setRequestInterceptor` methods to my app.js file, which gets the search/filtering function working, but I am still getting an `Expected array but received {}` error

```
RestangularProvider.setRestangularFields({
  id: '_id.$oid'
});

RestangularProvider.setRequestInterceptor(function(elem, operation) {

  if (operation === 'put') {
    elem._id = undefined;
    return elem;
  }
  return elem;
});
```

<strike>I have created a Plunker version that appears to be working correctly..
[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/LvX1Zboh1Tex5LFCgghQ?p=preview).</strike>

Created an updated Plunker with the issue I am seeing my local. The issue is that the Pagination is not working correctly. It is displaying only 10 items as I want it to, but clicking on the two does not switch to page 2. [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dNtmR4GCDGgpMQ8fBdB6)

Answer (score 0):

I saw several things wrong in your example. I believe you don't need the ng-controller="SearchCtrl" in your html. 
Also, the main point of having the filter in your ng repeat is to not use the watch event of the search text input. So you should use the products array and apply the filter against it. If you want to use filteredProducts, I left a function in my example below. I initialized the variables since I don't have access to your restless apis.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        if(input) {
            start = +start; //parse to int
            return input.slice(start);
        }
        return [];
    }
});

app.controller('paginationCtrl', ['$scope', '$log', '$filter', function ($scope, $log, $filter) {
   $scope.search = {name: "Product"}
   $scope.products = [{"_id": "0000000", "name":"Product", "description": "Product Description"},
   {"_id": "0000000", "name":"Product 2", "description": "Product Description 2"}];
      $scope.filteredProducts = [];
  
   $scope.currentPage = 2;
   $scope.maxSize = 100;
   $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
   $scope.startFrom = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;
   var filterProducts = function(newVal){
        $scope.filteredProducts.splice(0, $scope.filteredProducts.length);
         angular.forEach($scope.products, function(product) {
           if(product.name == newVal){
            $scope.filteredProducts.push(product);  
           }
       });
   }
   $scope.$watch('search.name', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        filterProducts(newVal);
       $scope.totalItems = $scope.filteredProducts.length;
   }, true);
   
    $scope.$watch('currentPage', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.startFrom = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;
   }, true);
    $scope.$watch('itemsPerPage', function(newVal, oldVal) {
       $scope.startFrom = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage;
   }, true);
  

   }])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
   <div ng-app="myApp">
            
     <div ng-controller="paginationCtrl as ctrl" class="row">
      
    <div class="col-lg-12">   
        <div class="pull-left">
                <div class="input-group product-searchs" >
                    <label class="sr-only" for="searchProducts">Search</label>
                    <span class="input-group-addon search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search.name" placeholder="Search for products" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon clear-icon">
                        <button type="button" ng-click="clearSearch()">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true">test</i>
                        </button>
                    </span>       
                </div>           
            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="list-group">
            <a ui-sref="productDetails({id:product._id})"  class="list-group-item clearfix" ng-repeat="product in products | filter: search.name  | limitTo: itemsPerPage | startFrom: 0  ">
                {{product.name}} 
                {{product.description}}
                <br/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <pagination class="pull-right" page="currentPage" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" ng-change="pageChanged()" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**Edit**
After watching your plunker, you do not need to add the filteredProducts to your controller since you are doing the filtering in your view. By adding the filteredProducts to your view, it will also be accessible in your controller with $scope.filteredProducts.
So replace the bottom of your html with the code below and also delete all that code that handles the filteredProducts from your controller:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="list-group">
            <a ui-sref="productDetails({id:product._id})" class="list-group-item clearfix" ng-repeat="product in filteredProducts = (products | filter: search.name | limitTo: itemsPerPage | startFrom: 0)  ">
              {{product.name}}<br/>
              {{product.description}}
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <pagination class="pull-right" page="currentPage" total-items="filteredProducts.length" ng-model="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" ng-change="pageChanged()" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
        </div>
```

If you want to do everything manually (which I do not recommend), you have to change your html to be product in filteredProducts, when it starts add all your products to the filteredProducts list and keep your code in the controller. Also you will have to fill the filteredProducts list again when the search is empty.

Comment: I am still having an issue getting this to work in my code. I get an error that $scope.filteredProducts.splice is not a function. Although when I used the same code above in a new file I was able to get it to function correctly. The only difference that I can see is my Restangular service, which I have added to my original post.

Comment: Can you create a plunkr with the basics of your example? Maybe the filterFilter function is not returning an array.

Comment: I was having some issues creating a plunkr, but I did some comparing between the demo and my code. The the main difference is in the demo you define `$scope.products` within the pagination-controller, but in my code I did not define. `$scope.products` is defined in my `products-controller.js`. Do I need to redefine `$scope.products` or query my database again within my pagination-controller?

Comment: I also noticed that I was using my old ng-repeat when I was getting the `$scope.filteredProducts.splice` is not a function. When I change the ng-repeat to match what was provided in the example above I get the `Error:[filter:notArray] Expected array but recieved {}`

Comment: I didn't see your products-controller in your example. If the paginationCtrl is inside the products-controller, then you have to access it like $scope.$parent.products. Also keep in mind that I removed the ng-controller="SearchCtrl" from the html since I don't think it is needed.

Comment: I removed the ng-controller="SearchCtrl" from my code. I am linking my products-controller using ui-router. And when I tried $scope.parent.products.length to make sure I am getting my products I am getting undefined

Comment: $scope.$parent, you forgot the last $

Comment: Sorry I am using two computers at the moment, so I mistyped. I had $scope.$parent.products.length

Comment: is your pagination controller inside the products controller? I'm talking about the html.

Comment: yeah within my products.html I have an ng-controller="paingation-controller" at the top level of my file. I do not have a ng-controller for my products-controller tho. That is being linked via my ui-router.

Comment: It should still work fine. Can you try adding your products-controller in the html file and remove the one from the ui router? so you can have something like <div ng-controller="products-controller"> {{$scope.products}} <div ng-controller="pagination-controller"> </div></div> and lets see if you get any output

Comment: what happens if you replace this line of code: $scope.filteredProducts = filterFilter($scope.products, newVal); with $scope.filteredProducts = [{"_id": ObjectID("0000000"), "name":"Product", "description": "Product Description"}];

Comment: I commented the code you provided, and uncommented my old code. Then made the change. Still getting the filter:notarray.

Comment: I'm sorry Herr Josua, without a plunkr or jsfiddle it is going to be really difficult to help.

Comment: I edited my answer (look at the bottom of my answer), let me know if you have any problems. When I typed "Product 01" it worked fine.

Comment: I went ahead and edited my view, but when I removed/commented all the code that handled $scope.filteredProducts pagination stops working. I have updated my plunker.